# Uploading base64 results in a outofmemory error in a Android app

Tags: java, android, image, out-of-memory

I'm back with a problem.

I'm trying to create a Android application that allows the user to search a image from their gallery and upload it. However on high resolution images the application will crash with a out of memory error.

The image is 1,7MB and a resolution of 1944x1944px.

After the users opens a picture from their gallery it will be loaded in a imageview, I already resized the picture to 150x150 pixels to prevent crashes there.

Code:

```
            Button buttonUploadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadImage);
        buttonUploadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", 
                        "Uploading...", true);  

                    new Thread(){
                        @Override
                        public void run(){



                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);         
                        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);    bitmap.recycle();
                        byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();


                        String image_str = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, columnIndex2);
                        bitmap = null;
                        System.gc();


                        try{

                            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://example.com/android.php");

                            List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", image_str));
                            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
                            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                            inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
                            //Json stuff here to handle the response and see if it succeeded or not.
```

Error message: (I hope this is allowed)
[Error message](http://hastebin.com/alehidageg.avrasm)
I already tried bitmap = null and System.gc() but both didn't help.

Ofcourse I can upload it in chuncks, but shouldn't Android be able to upload a 1.7MB image without any problems?

Thanks already!

Comment: What's the original format of the image? If it is jpeg, the png version you use for upload could be much larger. Also the string representation takes roughly 2 2/3 of that memory and you have that at least twice (`image_str` and as part of the request).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are finished with the bitmap, `bitmap.recycle()` is probably what you are looking for.

check this for more info on managing bitmap memory.

https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

Edit: I just noticed you are calling that (two logical statements on one line is quite hard to read).

Second Edit: It seems the issue is that you are making several representations of the image other than the bitmap (a byte array, a string and a URLEncodedFormEntity), the System.gc() call is probably cleaning up the byte array. A quick google provided an example that is using a buffer to send a file http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106

Comment: Rewrote the application using this tutorial, now works without any issues. (this is even better because our Windows, OSX and iOS application don't use base64 either) I can't upvote you (yet) but I accepted your answer. Thank you :)